# Polyline Fusion table action on click

Tags: google-fusion-tables, polyline

I've edit this function :

In the first part of the code ,I display polyline from my fusion table. In the seconde part I want to affect an event on click to change style of polyline selected, but he doesn't work, he hidde all polylines..

```
function filterTC() {

var filter = [];
  var j = document.getElementsByName('sousmenu4');
 for (var i = 0, k; k = j[i]; i++) {
if (k.checked) {
  filter.push('\'' + k.value + '\'');
}
}

 if (filter.length) {
 if (!layer3.getMap()) {
 layer3.setMap(map);
 }
       layer3.setOptions({
      query: {
      select: 'geometry',
   from: '1twRoA12Qc7toIRQe_Uk6XKFS8Ts-V_AvcHZahGlx',
   where: '\'indice\' IN (' + filter.join(',') + ')',

 },
 options: {
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 3
  }

});

} 
else {
layer3.setMap(null);
}
```

The problem is with the code below :

```
    selected={};

google.maps.event.addListener(layer3, 'click', function(e) {
var val=e.row['name'].value,
    vals=[];

//update the selected-object
selected[val]=(!selected[val])?true:false;


for(var l in selected){
  if(selected[l]){
     vals.push(l);
  }
}

layer3.set("styles", [{
  where: "'name' IN('"+vals.join("','")+"')",
  polylineOptions: {
strokeColor: "#cc0000",
strokeWeight: "4"  }
}]);
  });   

}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the issue?  Is there a question?

Comment: issue is to change the style of polyline selected.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.